# How to fix screen size in web works for BB 10 app

Tags: javascript, html, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

I use the bellow code for fixing screen sizes as bb10 device height and width but the problem is when I scroll app on bb10 device up it scrolls whole app on up side and when I scroll down it scrolls whole app on down side.
Please help me how to fix it.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height,
            initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, 
            user-scalable=no">`

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "up side" and "down side"?

Comment: @Trendy means when I scroll BB 10(Z10) screen from top to bottom then it scrolls whole app screen from top to bottom side and when I scroll screen from bottom to top then it scroll whole app screen from bottom to top side.I want to fix this scrolling and whole app must contained within device height and width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the viewport you should be using this newer method. The way you've done it used to work , but this is now the recommended way:

```
<!-- set viewport -->
<script>
  var meta = document.createElement("meta");
  meta.setAttribute('name','viewport');
  meta.setAttribute('content','initial-scale='+ (1/window.devicePixelRatio) + ',user-scalable=no');
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
</script>
```